# Silver RSI indicator - zero gradient for one hour

Tags: trading, algorithmic-trading, forex, technical-indicator

I have been following the value of silver recently. My question concerns the RSI indicator for silver US$ / OZ (symbol: SILVER),  on 9th July 21:00 - 21:59. The indicator gradient was zero for that hour. The chart below copied from TradingView (1 minute) shows equal opening and closing values with no variation. Interestingly, silver was 'overbought' (above 70 RSI) after this period.

I'm new to trading but I'd like to know what situation would cause the silver RSI indicator to behave that way.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Q** : *"... **what situation**
> would **cause the silver RSI indicator** to behave that way <sub>( zero gradient for one hour )</sub> ?"*

The Silver-trading ( an XAGUSD on typical FX-Broker mediated access to market, used as an example ) exhibits during a regular trading week each day a one hour long period, when the market is closed. I.e. not producing any Quotes, not receiving any XTO-Orders to be executed AtMarket. The exact time of the market being closed is given by the Terms & Conditions of your Market-Access mediator ( plus GMT-offsets, Daylight Savings Time shifts and Bank Holidays create more surprises for us, if being unaware or less pedantic in making the software to deploy only if using a TZ-fully-qualified time, both for the respective Banking Holiday calenders and the Broker T&C and our Trading platform automation  <sub>... at least be warned about these known troubles ...</sub> )

This is the ***WHY*** reason for having a known "gap" in the flow of the TimeSeries-data. Given your data-processing assumed using an absolute-time (not the Open-Market relative-time), your Indicator must have produced the RSI-values that have surprised you (as the "gap" is both principal and long enough to "visually" remind you about this processing-artifact.

> Knowing this
> the rest is 
> easy ...

Answer (score 0):

The relative strength index (RSI) is based on price changes, the original formula can be simplified to:

```
diff[t] = close[t] - close[t-1]
rsi[t] = RMA(max(diff[t],0),length)/RMA(abs(diff[t]),length)*100
```

where `RMA` is the function of a Wilder moving average with period `length` *(the RMA can be described as an exponential moving average where the smoothing coefficient is `1/length`)*.

So the RSI can be described as the ratio between the RMA of positive price changes and the RMA of the absolute price changes, this result is then multiplied by 100.

In the chart you are showing, during the period where price changes are equal to 0, the value of both the RMA of positive price changes and absolute price changes decay exponentially without reaching 0 *(this is because the RMA is an IIR filter)*

Finally, when the bullish candle occurs, we have both the RMA of positive price changes and the RMA of absolute price changes approximately equal to each other, thus giving a result for the RSI approximately equal to 100.

[image]